# What's the best method to let the users access the file in Openstack Swift?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

We are one of the Openstack cloud user and use Swift to store lots of files in cloud. And our users (the end-users) will access these files. If the files are public, then the end-users can directly visit the object URL in web or mobile applications. However, some of files are private. Each end-user can only access his own private files.

The end-user may have two methods to access his private files:

> A. The end-user always sends requests to our server. And our server will get the files from Swift, and then send them to the user. In this
>   method, Our server can be regarded as a file proxy. We have the
>   authentication of Openstack, and the user has the authentication of
>   our server. We should maintain our own user system.
>
> One problem of this method is the scalability. Because each request
>   will be sent to our server, then the server will be the bottleneck if
>   many files are uploading or downloading at the same time. The high
>   scalability feature of Swift can't be used if we don't have enough
>   servers. Actually we really don't need lots of servers except file
>   transferring.
>
> B. The end-user directly sends requests to Swift. It may solve the huge file bandwidth problem. But he must have the authentication
>   method of Openstack. So we need thousands of Openstack accounts for
>   our users while we are only one of the user of Openstack! It seems
>   strange and is not feasible.

Are there any other methods to meet the requirement?

Comment: You can use B option with all user authenticate by a single username/password which is an reseller admin defined in their Swift auth system, you can create different Swift Account for different user but use the same token to access.

Comment: Then how to let User A not access User B's files? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use your server to get the files (scenario A), but put *that* server "in the cloud". Then as access needs to scale up, you spin up additional servers under a load balancer. You, therefore, are distributing the load horizontally as needed.

An idea.

(Disclaimer: I am a Rackspace employee)

Comment: Thanks. It seems that adding more servers is the best method to solve this problem, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

A third idea is to use swift's tempurl feature, when a client needs a file, you genenerate a signed url to the file, having checked checked if they are authorised, and the url they get enables them to download directly from swift,
so two problems are solved

```
1. User A can not get User B's files
2. Download is straight from swift, so your server does not become the bottleneck for downloads (only for authorization).
```